# Kafka Streams - Forward record in init()

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In a custom `Transformer`, we try to create and forward some records in the `init(..)` method. According to the [Kafka Streams JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-), this should be possible. However, this is not working and we are getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "my-app-0.0.16-3be1aa47-d51d-4b0c-821a-a0b850359490-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: failed to initialize processor KSTREAM-TRANSFORM-0000000004
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.init(ProcessorNode.java:95)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initTopology(StreamTask.java:517)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeTopology(StreamTask.java:267)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.transitionToRunning(AssignedTasks.java:253)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.initializeNewTasks(AssignedTasks.java:79)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAndRestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:318)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:839)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:115)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:146)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:93)
```

Am I getting the JavaDoc wrong and it is simply not possible to emit records from `init`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you misunderstood the [transform API](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-).As per the definition,transform each record of the input stream into zero or more records in the output stream.

Within the Transformer, the state is obtained via the ProcessorContext.Processor interface has the init method.The init() method passes in a ProcessorContext instance, which provides access to the metadata of the currently processed record, including its source Kafka topic and partition, its corresponding message offset, and further such information.

Now we have the access of context using the init method, then we can call forward method from context but not inside the init method.

You can see this example to [understand](http://codingjunkie.net/kafka-processor-part1/). Hope it would work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this and I additionally forward records using in the `transform(..)` method. However, the JavaDoc you referred to also states `Furthermore, via Punctuator.punctuate(long) the processing progress can be observed and additional periodic actions can be performed.` So if it is possible to forward records using a Punctuator (instantiated within the `init` method), I do not understand why it is not possible from the `init` method directly.

Comment: Moreover, the example in the JavaDoc contains a comment for the init method: `// can emit as many new KeyValue pairs as required via this.context#forward()`

Comment: @SörenHenning The comment `// can emit as many new KeyValue pairs as required via this.context#forward()` means within the registered `Punctuator`. Note, that it's two line comment with first line: `// punctuate each 1000ms; can access this.state`

Comment: As long as `init()` is running, Kafka Streams is still in startup phase and not ready to process data -- that's why you cannot `forward()` data within `init()`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @MatthiasJ.Sax and, indeed, I misunderstood the docs.
Thus, in order to emit some records once in the beginning of processing, would it make sense to schedule a `Punctuator` with a duration of e.g. 1ms and then cancel it after the first call?

Comment: Or can this not be considered to be "save"?

Comment: `StreamThread` first processed messages, and afterwards check for punctuations. Thus, you don't get any guarantee that it's executed before the first record is processed. If you don't need this guarantee, it save otherwise. (cf. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L890 and https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L911)